# how to create Dictionary within a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have data in this format in a text file.
All I want is to covert this content in dictionary within a dictionary data structure

```
('Marks_Subjects ', "[['Time', 'maths', 'Science', 'english'], ['2013-08-31-16', 100, 50, 65], ['2013-08-31-17', 90, 50, 65], ['2013-08-31-18', 80, 60, 85]]")
```

I want the output to be like:-

```
{'Marks': {'maths': {'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects': '100'}},

               'Science':{'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects': '50'}},

               'maths':{'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects': '65'}}} and so on for 17:00 and 18:00 too
```

Here is the code snippet:-

```
import sys
import json
def module2():
    title, data = ('Marks_Subjects ', "[['Time', 'maths', 'Science','english'],['2013-08-31-16', 100, 50, 65], ['2013-08-31-17', 90, 50, 65],['2013-08-31-18', 80, 60, 85]]")
    title, sub_title = title.split('_')
    data = json.loads(data.replace("'", '"'))
    data = dict(zip(*data))
    date = data.pop('Time')
    #for subject, value in data.iteritems():
    print {title: {subject: {date: {sub_title: value}} for subject, value in data.iteritems()}}
```

module2()

I split the title Marks_Subjects so that Marks is my Title and Subjects is my sub_title. 
json.loads converts a unicode string into a python data structure 
data.zip maps the indexes of the 2 lists.
The problem here is that I am getting this error

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required

I guess this means that the zip function can only zip 2 lists. I want to zip the indexes of first list that is ["Time", "Maths", "Science", "English"] with the rest of the lists.

So I guess a loop has to be run in order to achieve this. But I need some help doing that.

If I have 2 lists in my 'data' then it works just fine.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please be more specific with your issue.

Comment: I am stuck at the beginning only. All I have is the above saved in a text file and I have to convert it into a dictionary. Since I am new to python. I am kinda stuck where to start from as I am unable to figure out how to get rid of the '_' so that Marks and Subjects are considered separate. Can you provide any help? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import json
>>> title, data = ('Marks_Subjects ', "[['Time', 'maths', 'Science', 'english'], ['2013-08-31-16', 100, 50, 65]]")
>>> title, sub_title = title.split('_')  # Split 'Mark' and 'Subjects'
>>> data = json.loads(data.replace("'", '"'))  # Deserialize the data list
>>> data = dict(zip(*data))  # make a dict of the two lists
>>> date = data.pop('Time')  # Extract the date
>>> # Create a dict using a comprehension.
...
>>> {title: {subject: {date: {sub_title: mark}}
...  for subject, mark in data.iteritems()}}
{'Marks': {'maths': {'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects ': 100}}, 'Science': {'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects ': 50}}, 'english': {'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects ': 65}}}}
```

I must say that this data structure doesn't make sense.

Comment: What if there were 9 list inside instead of 2?

Comment: hey mate, now I have more than 1 lists inside data. How do zip will map the indexes of the first list with the rest of the lists? Thanks

Comment: @aman `zip` just takes `n` element from each list and creates a tuple from it. `dict` will create a dictionary out of a list containing tuples of two elements. If there are multiple input lists, this will result in a tuple of a size equal to the number of input lists (in your case 9).  Aside from this, don't call me "mate" this sounds demeaning.